# Linq Outer Joins - don't want DefaultIfEmpty, rather want NullIfEmpty

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

all,

This problem relates to the Dynamics CRM 2011 Linq provider - which does have a LOT of quirks.  However, I have not tagged it such as I *think* this is a general Linq question.

I have a class- Product.  It has a property (say ProductPrice) of type Price.

I am doing an Outer Join on this in Linq.  The CRM documentation says outer joins are not possible, but it seems to work (with the obvious problem I am asking here).

So say I am doing something like: (apologies for the pseudo linq)

```
        IList<Product> products = (from p in xrmContext.Products 
                                  join pr in xrmContext.Prices
                                  on p.ProductId equals pr.ProductId into prx from prices in prx.DefaultIfEmpty
                                  select new Product { ProductName = p.productName, ProductPrice = new Price { Amount = prices.PriceValue }).ToList();
```

This works great to a point.  It creates all the products irrespective of whether they have a price object or not.  Tippety top.

The problem is the DefaultIfEmpty.  As you are no doubt aware if a product has no price this DefaultIfEmpty will create a 'default' price object ... i.e. an object with null values.  What I *actually* want is NO price object - i.e. null, not a 'blank' object.

How is that possible?

I have worked round it by testing for a blank price name - ProductPrice = price.priceName == "" ? null : new Price ...

It would be nice to be able to do something like NullIfEmpty.  Any ideas?

Comment: This *is* LINQ provider specific because for example LINQ to SQL *does* generate a null reference in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the join:

```
from p in xrmContext.Products 
let price = xrmContext.Prices.FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.ProductID == p.ProductID)
select new Product()
{ 
    ProductName = p.productName,
    ProductPrice = price != null ? new Price() { Amount = price.PriceValue } : null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

crm 2011 linq doesn't support outer join. 
If you try Amiram's code - when evaluating the select,  you'll get an error "products doesn't contain attribute "pricevalue"".